# OpenVPN cannot access internet when connected

Tags: openvpn

I’m attempting to setup OpenVPN on our server. The server is running Centos 7. After installing and configuring OpenVPN I can successfully connect from a Windows 10 client. But once connected I cannot access the internet. I also cannot ping the host server. Not related to OpenVPN, my server also uses KVM running multiple VM’s on a virtual network. I can also not ping the VM's when connected.

Host connection: 192.168.1.10
VPN network: 10.8.0.0
Virtual network: 10.8.8.0

I confirmed IP forwarding is enabled. I also updated Iptables with:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I listed below the OpenVPN server.conf and Ifconfig info.

I've been struggling with this for a week. At this point I'm stuck and not sure what to look at next. Any ideas?

**OpenVPN server.conf:**

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun

ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh2048.pem

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 192.168.1.10 255.255.255.255"
push "route 10.8.8.0 255.255.255.0"

push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"

keepalive 10 120
user nobody
group nobody

persist-key
persist-tun

status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
client-to-client

explicit-exit-notify 1
```

**Ifconfig:**

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::3bcd:ddd4:4650:6087  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ac:1f:6b:05:cc:96  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 454678  bytes 136137391 (129.8 MiB)
        RX errors 36  dropped 37074  overruns 0  frame 36
        TX packets 213347  bytes 80743075 (77.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 91899  bytes 50703642 (48.3 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 91899  bytes 50703642 (48.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.8.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.8.0.2
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.8.8.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.8.8.255
        ether 52:54:00:34:2a:4d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2663  bytes 193301 (188.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2582  bytes 226983 (221.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe6e:e2f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:54:00:6e:0e:2f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2663  bytes 230583 (225.1 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 141674  bytes 7459999 (7.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Update regarding accessing the VM's from a VPN connection:

When the libvirtd virtual bridge starts, iptables need to be modified to route VPN traffic to the VM's. Executing the following two firewall-cmd commands will manually insert the required rules. This will need to be done if firewall-cmd --reload, or any other command that restores firewalld rules, is executed.

Assumptions:

- Virtual network device created for KVM is named virbr0 with subnet of 10.10.0.0/20 (adjust here and below as needed if virtual network was created under different device name).
- OpenVPN device is named tun0 with subnet of 10.8.0.0/24

  ```
  firewall-cmd --direct --passthrough ipv4 -I FORWARD 3 -d 10.10.0.0/20 -i tun0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
  firewall-cmd --direct --passthrough ipv4 -I FORWARD 4 -s 10.10.0.0/20 -i virbr0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
  ```

Verify entries by executing iptables -t filter -S your should see the following amongst all the rules listed:

```
-A FORWARD -d 10.10.0.0/20 -i bridge0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.10.0.0/20 -i virbr0 -o bridge0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.10.0.0/20 -i tun0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.10.0.0/20 -i virbr0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
```

Note: The previous two firewall-cmd commands that were executed added the 3rd and 4th lines shown.

If needed, executing the following two firewall-cmd commands will manually remove the inserted rules.

```
    firewall-cmd --direct --passthrough ipv4 -D FORWARD -d 10.10.0.0/20 -i tun0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
    firewall-cmd --direct --passthrough ipv4 -D FORWARD -s 10.10.0.0/20 -i virbr0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
```

Verify entries by executing iptables -t filter -S your should see the following amongst all the rules listed:

```
-A FORWARD -d 10.10.0.0/20 -i bridge0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.10.0.0/20 -i virbr0 -o bridge0 -j ACCEPT
```

Note: The previous two firewall-cmd commands that were executed removed the 3rd and 4th lines that were shown above.

Issue: The libvirtd service will overwrite the rules added above on boot or restart. To get around this, add the following two libvirt scripts.

Script # 1: On start or reconnection of any VM associated with virbr0 (this will also execute on boot or by executing systemctl start libvirtd):

vi */etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu* and insert the following:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    # Only execute this script if the opennebula-controller VM is started or reconnected
    if [ "${1}" = "opennebula-controller=" ] ; then

        # Check if vpn input routing rule exists. If not add it.
        iptables -C FORWARD -d 10.10.0.0/20 -i tun0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT > /dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? = 1 ] ; then
            if [ "${2}" = "started" ] || [ "${2}" = "reconnect" ]; then
                firewall-cmd --direct --passthrough ipv4 -I FORWARD 3 -d 10.10.0.0/20 -i tun0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
            fi
        fi

        # Check if vpn output routing rule exists. If not add it.
        iptables -C FORWARD -s 10.10.0.0/20 -i virbr0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT > /dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? = 1 ] ; then
            if [ "${2}" = "started" ] || [ "${2}" = "reconnect"  ]; then
                firewall-cmd --direct --passthrough ipv4 -I FORWARD 4 -s 10.10.0.0/20 -i virbr0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
            fi
        fi

    fi
```

Write and close

Script # 2: On stop of the libvirtd daemon (this removes the rules so that on restart or by executing systemctl stop libvirtd, duplicate rules will not be inserted)

vi */etc/libvirt/hooks/daemon* and insert the following:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    # Check if vpn input routing rule exists. If it does, remove it.
    iptables -C FORWARD -d 10.10.0.0/20 -i tun0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT > /dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? = 0 ] ; then
            if [ "${2}" = "shutdown" ]; then
                firewall-cmd --direct --passthrough ipv4 -D FORWARD -d 10.10.0.0/20 -i tun0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
            fi
        fi

    # Check if vpn output routing rule exists. If it does, remove it.
    iptables -C FORWARD -s 10.10.0.0/20 -i virbr0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT > /dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? = 0 ] ; then
            if [ "${2}" = "shutdown" ]; then
                firewall-cmd --direct --passthrough ipv4 -D FORWARD -s 10.10.0.0/20 -i virbr0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
            fi
        fi
```

Write and close

Comment: It turns out the I had LZO compression (comp-lzo) specified in my client configuration but not the server configuration. Once I corrected that issue I can now access the internet and the rest of the network. Now the only thing I have to solve for is accessing the VM's from a VPN connection.

Comment: Did you ever solve your 2nd problem with communication between the VMs? If not, I suspect the issue is that your systems are really in different networks without a route to talk to each other. I'd be interested to know what solutions you found, if any.

Comment: Please see the update to my original posting above. This addition to my post is from notes that I recorded after solving the issue last year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had LZO compression (comp-lzo) specified in my client configuration but not the server configuration. Once I corrected that issue I can now access the internet and the rest of the network.